# Program recognizes a copy of itself in the operating system

Tags: process, operating-system, bots, createprocess, malware

I'm trying to create a piece of software that will not be susceptible to bots. Is there a way for me to code into a program a way to check in the operating system for a process just like it and then put in a shutdown mechanism if it is recognized. Think of something like netflix where if one tab in chrome is running netflix, a second tab being opened will display an "oops" message. Is there anything like this for something that does not run on a web browser? What should I be looking into?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to be *way more specific* about what you're trying to achieve. The possible answers range from “easy” to “impossible”.

Comment: Sure, you can look for running processes under the same user named the same thing, but what does that have to do with bots/malware? And people could either just run it under a different user or copy/rename the app and run it again.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is create a program that plays music in a decentralized network. I'm trying to make sure a person cannot "double play" a song from the network if working on the same machine. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There can be plenty of solutions; the first coming into my mind are:

1) your program checks for existence of a particular file; if the files is not found then the program continue, otherwise your programs know that another instance is running and thus can terminate immediately. If the file is not found, your program creates it and then delete it before exting.

2) you can use an operating system call or an o.s. utility program to know if another instance of your program is running (e.g.: in linux, the command ps)

have fun